# Can I wire R from AC system and R from heating system to single R terminal on thermostat?

Tags: thermostat

I want to replace existing thermostat that controls both heat and AC.

There are two cables coming out of the wall. One goes to heating system with a red wire and a white wire,
the other goes to to the AC unit with a red, yellow and green wire.

On the old thermostat one red wire went to R and the other went to RC. There is no jumper on this thermostat. The new thermostat has a single red terminal.

Should I only connect one of the red wires to this?

If so should I use the one from the AC system or the heating system. Or, as an alternative should I wire both red wires to the same R terminal on the thermostat?

Comment: Careful - if you do, you could find 48V between some of the wires on the 'stat.  They're separate because they're sourced from different transformers and they may be out of phase!

Comment: What make and model is this new thermostat you're trying to put in?